# String replace first occurence of a needle, ignore others

Tags: php

I want to do a str_replace such that it replaces the first needle (out of an array of needles) and ignores the rest of the needles in the string.

This doesn't do it:

```
str_replace ( $needles, $replace , $mystring, 1 )
```

Say for example

```
$needles = array('#a#', '#b#');
$replace = array ('1', '2');
$mystring = "this #b# is #b# a test #a# string";
```

I want to parse $mystring so that it's output is:

```
$mystring = "this 2 is a test string";
```

So the first needle it finds follows the rule indicated in the replace array, and all subsequent needles are replaced with a blank string.

Hope that makes sense, it's hard to explain in words my idea.

Comment: There's nothing built-in to do this, you'll have to write a loop.

Comment: [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) has an optional limit argument; but it won't remove matches after limit is met

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got a pretty good solution for you (also fast), no loops required:

```
$replace = array( //This will make your life really easy
    "#a#" => 1,
    "#b#" => 2
);

$pattern = "/(" . implode("|", array_keys($replace)) . ")/" ;
$string = "this #b# is #b# a test #a# string";

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

$string = preg_replace("/{$matches[0][0]}/", "{$replace[$matches[0][0]]}", $string, 1);
$string = preg_replace($pattern, "", $string);

echo $string ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have loops to get this effect:

```
$needles = array('/#b#/', '/#a#/');
$replace = array ('2', '1');
$mystring = "this #b# is #b# a test #a# string";
for ($i=0; $i<count($needles); $i++) {
   $repl = preg_replace ( $needles[$i], $replace[$i], $mystring, 1 );
   if ($repl != $mystring) break; // 1st replacement done
}
for ($i=0; $i<count($needles); $i++)
   $repl = preg_replace ( $needles[$i], '', $repl, 1 );
var_dump($repl);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
string(25) "this 2 is  a test  string"
```

Comment: Your code replaces the first needle in the order of the `needles` array, not in their order of appearance in the text, which is what the OP needs. Specifically, you had to change the array order just to get the example to output the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$needles = array('#a#', '#b#');
$replace = array('1', '2');
$mystring = "this #b# is #b# a test #a# string";

$start = PHP_INT_MAX;
foreach ($needles as $needle)
    if ((int)$start != ($start = min(strpos($mystring, $needle), $start)))
        $replacement = $replace[$key = array_flip($needles)[$needle]];
$mystring = str_replace($needles, "", substr_replace($mystring, $replacement, $start, strlen($needles[$key])));
```

*Output:*

```
var_dump($mystring);
// =>
string(25) "this 2 is  a test  string"
```